# Navigation Drawer not drawing over toolbar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I'm trying to implement a `NavigationDrawer`:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_content_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        setupNavigation()

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun setupNavigation() {
        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, binding.drawerMain, R.string.open, R.string.close)
            .also { toggle ->
                binding.drawerMain.addDrawerListener(toggle)
                toggle.syncState() //TODO: find out what it does
            }
    }
}
```

And my `themes` file which is the default one:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Rocketman" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that the drawer isn't on top, it's below the toolbar:
[image]

The answers on SO are very outdated (most from 2016).

How do I make my `NavigationDrawer` display over the toolbar?

Comment: I think your provided layout is trimmed .. can you provide the entire layout

Comment: @Zain it's not trimmed, the only thing missing is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom Toolbar instead of the default SupportActionBar, to do that.

Select a NoActionBar app theme

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Rocketman" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Add a custom Toolbar to the layout

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!--    Main Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>
    
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_content_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Set the SupprtActionBar with `setSupportActionBar()` right after `setContentView()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(actionbar)

    setupNavigation()

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
}
```